# How to measure, order, install exterior door

Tags: doors

I'd like to order an exterior door for this old wooden thing in my basement. However I can't see how it's installed into the concrete. The frame looks to be simple 2-by stock and I don't see evidence of any tap screws that connect wood  to concrete on the sides or bottom. Where should I look for fastening? And what considerations for ordering the replacement?

[image]

Comment: Just replacing the door or door and frame?  Doors usually come in standard sizes, 30,32 34 inches.  If the door and frame then measure the rough(block to block) opening.  The screws are probably behind the door stops.

Comment: Take some pictures of the frame with the door opened. What's 2-by stock?

Comment: 2-by: US dimensioned lumber. The most common size for framing is a nominal "two-by-four" inches in cross section; the actual standardized size is smaller than that for arcane historical reasons but it's still referred to by the nominal dimensions. Door frames are more likely to be one-by, still nominal.

Comment: Is this, in fact, an exterior door? If so, a complete, pre-hung exterior door would likely be the best way to go. If it's an interior door, but you just want an exterior grade door, you may consider ordering just a replacement door so you don't have to mess with the frame.

Comment: @FreeMan *this* particular door leads to the outside, but you're correct it not *an* exterior door and yes I intend to replace it and the frame with a prehung exterior door. My question is that I don't see how the frame is adhered to the concrete, as I would assume I'd install the new door the same way.

Comment: Sorry, that was the question I intended to ask and failed to do. You did interpret it correctly. Good communication is hard. :( As noted above, pics of the door frame will help us help you ID how it was attached. It's likely screwed behind the weather stripping or the door stops, possibly long screws through the hinges, too. There may be wood embedded into the concrete for the door to be installed in - that would have been nice of the original builders.

Comment: Depending on how old the home is, you might not be able to find a standard-sized pre-hung door to fit this opening without either cutting or a lot of filling of gaps. What is the measurement of the door itself?

Comment: What's wrong with this door?  Aside from needing paint it looks in pretty good shape and you'll have to buy a high end (by today's standards) door just to match its quality.  What's the goal?

Comment: @jay613 Perhaps the picture doesn't show it well, but this is a hollow-core door that leads outside. The panels have little if any R value to boast of, and though the outside stoop is covered and generally dry, the age is starting to show. It's old and/or warped and possibly poorly built. I can't close it, the latch bold holds it fast. Sure I could remortise the jamb and buy a new knob for cheap, but we live in a fairly nice neighborhood and I'm trying to tackle little eyesores one at a time. This would be a great mudroom and storage spot for gardening supplies.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the screws for the jamb are hidden behind the hinges, or double as hinge screws.

Sometimes screws are sunk and covered by filler before the jamb is painted.

If you are replacing the jamb anyway, you can wreck it, or you can run a reciprocal saw with a metal cutting blade between jamb and concrete. Remove the door slab first so you have some room to maneuver the saw and wiggle the jamb. Save the "shaker" style door slab for a different project or a give-away.

Then measure the RO (Rough Opening) and depending how square the opening is, add margin for wedging: at least 1/4in at the narrowest point.

When inserting the jamb, pour a bit of cement under the bottom "threshold" plate of the door so that it is level, has full support, and no gaps. Let the cement harden with the jamb in place.

If you live in a moist climate, include sill gasket between cement/concrete and door jamb.

The cement can be pre-mix variety, just not concrete which has stones in it. Leveling is done by tapping and aligning the jamb & threshold while the cement is not cured ("wet"). Just push down the threshold (with gasket) and let the cement ooze out. No self-levelling cement needed.

For that little bit I use left-over tile cement (not mastic glue) because it bonds well without concrete primer, and the polymers in it -before curing- provide some helpful elasticity while adjusting the jamb.

Comment: "If you live in a moist climate," I live in Seattle, humidity is 75-80% most of the year. Current install lacks a sill gasket among other things. I assume the concrete should be a "leveling" variety...

Comment: I would suggest not having the wooden jamb rest directly on the concrete, especially one exposed to the outside moisture. Paint or seal the endgrain on the jamb and wrap some sort of moisture barrier there first.

Comment: @spuck yes, hence the sill gasket (last sentence)

Comment: @AdamO Seattle, yes then sill gasket needed. (I am also west coast). The cement can be pre-mix variety, just not concrete which has stones in it. Leveling is done by tapping and aligning the jamb & threshold while the cement is not cured ("wet"). Just squish the threshold (with gasket) and let the cement ooze out. So you do not need self-levelling cement. For that little bit I use left-over tile cement (not mastic glue) because it bonds well without concrete primer and the polymers in it provide some helpful elasticity while adjusting the jamb.

Answer (score 1):

Check plumb of the sides to see if it’s way out, and measure the shortest width for your rough opening. (Outside of 2-by to outside of 2-by.) Take 1/2” off this for luck. Do this on the side not pictured as well, just in case something strange is going on with the block wall.

Same for height: measure to the top of the jamb 2-by. Plan to leave the higher one in place.

Don’t worry too much about the existing fastening — it’ll be clear when you start taking things apart. I’d remove the door and cut the jamb into sections with a reciprocating saw for easy prybar removal.

To fasten new, concrete screws into the foundation with low expand spray foam will do the trick.

Comment: I agree on all counts. I'd trace vertical lines right on the existing frame if it's way out of plumb. This gives you good size references. The existing jamb may be poured right in, possibly with an anchoring channel.

Comment: That's a poured wall, FYI. The lines are solid board form joints.

Answer (score 1):

In the past door and window bucks and frames were sometimes built on-site from dimensional lumber, secured into the concrete forms, and poured in place. I don't know how they were anchored into the concrete but I would guess either nails or screws partially embedded into the wood on the concrete side before the pour, or else they're held just by adhesion of the concrete.

I think the assumption that your new door should be anchored to the concrete in the same way as this original door is flawed. Make your own choice about how you'll anchor the new door and whether you'll install some pressure-treated lumber between the concrete and the jamb of the pre-hung door unit. Then grab your Universal Disassembly Tools and clear that old jamb out, however it happens to be attached. (images: harborfreight.com)

[image: sledge hammer] [image: recip saw]